# How to display List of enum - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

I am trying to display a list of books by category.

**Category.java**

```
public enum Category {
    NEW,
    CLASSIC,
    STANDARD;
}
```

**BookDto.java**

```
public class BookDto {

    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    private String publisher;

    private Category category;

    private int totalCount;

}
```

**RentController.java**

```
 @GetMapping("/booksCategory")
    public List<BookDto> getBookByCategory(@RequestParam Category category) {
        return rentService.getBookByCategory(category);
    }
```

**RentService.java**

```
 public List<BookDto> getBookByCategory(Category category) {
        List<Book> book = bookRepository.findAllBookByCategory(category);
        return mapBookListToBooDtoList(book);
    }
```

**BookRepository.java**

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
    
    @Query("select count(b) from Book b")
    List<Book> findAllBookByCategory(Category category);
}
```

From code above I am getting following error:

`Required Category parameter 'category' is not present`

Comment: Side note: consider not to mix resources (rentals, books, book-categories).in your REST API (/booksCategory returns BookDto in the RentController)

Comment: Yes I should put it in BookController and BookService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your query, you see that the parameter category is not used.
Also the query returns `count(b)` instead a books as required by the return type.

For simple queries you can omit the explicit query:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
    
    List<Book> findByCategory(Category category);
}
```

Also make sure you actually pass a category as a query parameter to the HTTP request when calling your service, e.g.: `GET https://my-service-url/booksCategory?category=CLASSIC`

Comment: Did you add something like `?category=CLASSIC` to your HTTP request?

Comment: No, should I? Like parameter

Comment: Your controller defined category as required RequestParam (= query parameter), so yes, when calling your service you must provide this query parameter.